# div transform is not working on mouseover with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent `div` and a child `div`. Now the function I want to perform is that when the coordinate of mouse x and y of the parent div is greater than 413 and 10, the child `div` should rotate. But its not working. I want to do it with JavaScript. So please tell me what is the mistake here.

By the way I am not getting any error in console.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var test = document.getElementsByClassName("parent-div");
  for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    test[i].addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
      var x = event.clientX;
      var y = event.clientY;
      console.log(x + " " + y);
      if (x > 413 && y > 10) {
        for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
          test[i].mousemove = function(idx) {
            this.classList.toggle("rotated");
            if (idx < test.length - 1) test[idx + 1].classList.toogle("rotated");
          }.bind(test[i], i);
        }
      }
    }, false);
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.parent-div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  perspective: 500px;
}

.child-div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div.rotated>div.child-div {
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div"></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you using `test[i].addEventListener("mousemove",...` first, and then inside that handler you overwrite it again using `test[i].mousemove = function(idx) {` …? Assigning event handlers inside event handlers usually doesn’t make much sense, and I can see any in it here either.

Comment: I want the coordinates of the mouse so that I can use it to determine where is the current position of the mouse and accordingly rotate the inner div.

Comment: And why would that need assigning a handler for the same event again, while you are already inside a handler function?

Comment: Please don’t post longer codes in comments, that is hardly readable. Edit your question instead, and format it properly.

Comment: The changed js code. but the part I have set as the comment doesn't work. What to do now?

Comment: for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++){
    test[i].mousemove=function(idx){
     this.classList.toggle("rotated");
     if(idx< test.length-1)test[idx + 1].classList.toogle("rotated");
    }.bind(test[i],i);
   }

Comment: This part is not working.

Comment: Well it's working now. Thanks